# Why does sed evaluate the result of this substitution as 8?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, terminal

I'm trying to get `sed` to output the first number it sees in a line of text. Here is the command I'm using:

```
sed 's/.*\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/g'
```

To my understanding, that should tell `sed` to take input from stdin, skip a bunch of characters until it hits a number, match and capture 1 or more characters of that number, and then skip the remaining characters in the line. However, this does not hold up when I try to pipe something through it:

```
james@DESKTOP-B1DARHA MINGW64 ~/Code/git/corefx (sparse-array-builder)
$ tasklist | grep VBCSCompiler
VBCSCompiler.exe             11080 Console                   33    155,944 K

james@DESKTOP-B1DARHA MINGW64 ~/Code/git/corefx (sparse-array-builder)
$ tasklist | grep VBCSCompiler | sed 's/.*\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/g'
8
```

I expected the output of the second command to be `11080`, but it's `8`. Why does this happen, given that 8 is not even the first or last number in the input, and grouped together with a bunch of characters that also match? Also, what would be the correct regexp to use here?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of your regex is greedily matching as much as it can, and leaving as little as possible for the next part of the match, which is the last digit in the string - as this digit is part of the memory usage, it can change between different executions of your pipeline.

If you set the first part of the regex to match any non-digit character, then it will pick out the number you want:

```
tasklist | grep VBCSCompiler | sed 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/'
```

Comment: It was late when I answered this :) It doesn't make a difference to the result, but I'll update anyway.